# Q-Q Residual Plots with unusual kinks for both FE OLS and Logistic Regression

Tags: logistic, least-squares, residuals, fixed-effects-model

I have a dataset on power plant generation, which can be found [here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/065a5e80158319e092a85b0d2342355920230813112840/86ac84).

I use both a FE OLS and a Logit Model (no/some generation)

```
library(fixest)

ihs <- function(x) {
  y <- log(x + sqrt(x ^ 2 + 1))
  return(y)
}
reg <- feols(ihs(daily_quantity) ~ drought_index : resource_psr_type_def + CDD + HDD + solar + wind + imports + exports| name + date,data=panel)

reg_logit_FE1 <- feglm(gen_any ~  drought_index:resource_psr_type_def + CDD + HDD + solar + wind + imports + exports | name + date, family=binomial(link="logit"),vcov=~name, data=panel)
```

However, when plotting the residuals, I get very strange patters, as can be seen from the Q-Q Plot. I don't understand where they are coming from - especially since i utilize two very different models and they show a similar pattern, following the x=y line pretty much exactly in for x between -1 and 1 and deviating immensely (with a kink for values of x below -1)

[image: Logit Q-Q Plot]
[image: OLS Q-Q Plot]

Comment: These are familiar patterns, because they are QQ plots for mixtures of three variables.  They suggest you are lacking a discrete explanatory variable.  Compare the lower plot to `qqnorm(x <- 1.5 * c(rnorm(2000, -4.5, 3/4), rnorm(8000, -0.5, 1), rnorm(300, 3, 1)))`